# A question on simple and unital $C^\star$-algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

There is a quotation of a book "$C^\star$-*algebras Finite-Dimensional Approximations*"

***Definition 1.7.4.*** A representation $\pi: A \rightarrow B(H)$ is called *essential* if $\pi(A)$ contains no nonzero compact operators. ($A$ is a $C^\star$-algebra.)

My question is If $A$ is a simple and unital $C^\star$-algebra, then all the representations on $A$ will be faithful and essential?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $A$ is simple, then indeed all representations will be faithful.

As for essential, the answer is trivially no if you consider $A=M_n(\mathbb C)$. In the infinite-dimensional case, the answer is yes: the question is reduced to whether a simple unital infinite-dimensional C$^*$-algebra can contain compact operators.

Let $J=\{x\in \pi(A):\ x \text{ is compact }\}$. Then one can show that $J$ is an ideal of $\pi(A)$, so either $J=\pi(A)$ (this is the finite-dimensional case) or $J=0$.

Comment: But, Is $J$ an ideal of $A$? As we know, for arbitrary $a\in A$ and $x\in J$, $ax$ must be a compact, but, I suppose, $ax$ may not contain in $J$ because $J=A \cap K(H)$.

Comment: If $x\in J$, in particular $x\in A$. For any $a\in A$, $ax\in A$ because $A$ is an algebra. And $ax$ is compact because compacts are an ideal. So $ax\in J$. In other words, the intersection of a subalgebra with an ideal is an ideal of the subalgebra.

Comment: Your welcome. I'd rather be reading that book than what I actually have to read...

Comment: Er...yeah I am reading this book recently, and , you know, I am a beginner of operator algebra. So i meet with a mass of
problems ... maybe i am too dull~ :)

Comment: I deeply love the topics Nate and Taka's book, and I like the way it is written. But it assumes a fair deal of background. Depending on how much you know, you might want to visit Davidson's and Paulsen's books, for instance.

Comment: Oh~Thanks, i will try to read the book you mentioned.

Comment: In the last line of your answer above, does $J=A$ makes any contradiction? I could not understand why it is the finite-dimensional case.

Comment: If $J=A$, then $A$ is a simple unital subalgebra of the compacts,  so it is isomorphic to $M_n(\mathbb C) $ for some $n$.

Comment: Do you mean since $1\in K(H)$, then , for a closed unit ball $S$ in $H$, S is compact. Hence $H$ is finite-dimensional which leads an contradiction to the assumption?

Comment: Yes, that is one way of seeing it.

Comment: Oh Thanks~Martin